Python: indexes of all keys being changed in a dictionary within a class's object instead of just one key
(Both Classes are at the bottom of the post)
Im trying to make a "world" in python looking from the top, the world is made up of a dictionary like
WorldDict = 
{
0: ["-","-","-"],
1: ["-","-","-"],
2: ["-","-","-"]
}

I'm trying to "spawn" a player into the world and im gettting stuck on the part where it "renders" the player(changing a - to a p in the coordinates on the dictionary).
This is the starting code:
import WorldClass
import CreatureClass

MyWorld = WorldClass.World(5, 5, "  -")
MyWorld.CreateWorld()

Player = CreatureClass.Creature("  P", "player", 100, 1, 10, 1, "1")

Doing MyWorld.PrintWorld() will just print the dictionary in a nice format. Current output:
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -

Heres the problem, When I do MyWorld.SpawnCreature("  P", Player) or even just directly changing the dict:
coordinates = (1,3)
MyWorld.WorldDict[coordinates[1]][coordinates[0]] = "  P"

it ends up making it look like this:
  -  P  -  -  -
  -  P  -  -  -
  -  P  -  -  -
  -  P  -  -  -
  -  P  -  -  -

Can someone tell me why its affecting the all of the indexes at 1 instead of just the one at 3?
What I want:
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  -  -  -  -
  -  P  -  -  -

Classes:
World:
import CreatureClass
class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, defaultchar):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.defaultchar = defaultchar
        self.WorldDict = {}

    def CreateWorld(self):

        defaultchunk = []

        for number in range(0, self.width):
            defaultchunk.append(self.defaultchar)

        for number in range(0, self.height):
            self.WorldDict[number] = defaultchunk

    def PrintWorld(self):
        WorldDictKeys = list(self.WorldDict.keys())
        for key in WorldDictKeys:
            print("".join(self.WorldDict[key]))

    def GetCoords(self, coords):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            item = self.WorldDict[coords[1]][coords[0]]
            return item

    def LocationIsEmpty(self, coords):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            if self.GetCoords(coords) == self.defaultchar:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def DrawOnWorld(self, coords, symbol):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            self.WorldDict[coords[1]][coords[0]] = symbol
            print(f"drew on points ({coords[0]},{coords[1]})")


    def ClearCoords(self, coords):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            self.DrawOnWorld(coords, self.defaultchar)


    def SpawnCreature(self, coords, aCreature):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            if aCreature.creaturehasbeenspawned:
                print("creature has already been spawned")
            else:
                aCreature.creaturehasbeenspawned = True
                aCreature.coords = coords
                self.DrawOnWorld(aCreature.coords, aCreature.symbol)


    def CoordsValid(self,coords):
        if coords[0] <= len(self.WorldDict[0]) - 1 and coords[1] in list(self.WorldDict.keys()) and coords[0] >= 0 and coords[1] >= 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def MoveCreature(self, aCreature, coords):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            beforecoords = aCreature.coords

            aCreature.coords = coords
            self.ClearCoords(beforecoords)
            self.DrawOnWorld(aCreature.coords, aCreature.symbol)

    def TryMoveCreature(self, aCreature, coords):
        if self.CoordsValid(coords):
            if self.LocationIsEmpty(coords):
                self.MoveCreature(aCreature, coords)


Creature:
class Creature:
    def __init__(self, symbol, type, defaulthealth, defaultmovespeed, defaultdamage, skill, team):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.type = type
        self.defathealth = defaulthealth
        self.defatmovespeed = defaultmovespeed
        self.defatdamage = defaultdamage
        self.skill = skill
        self.team = team
        self.health = defaulthealth
        self.movespeed = defaultmovespeed
        self.damage = defaultdamage
        self.creaturehasbeenspawned = False
        self.coords = None

I already described what happened, what I wanted to happen, and what I tried within the description of the post.

Does this answer your question? List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly

In your CreateWorld function, each row is the same object, so when you change one, you change all of them.
A way to fix that would look like this (using list comprehension):
    def CreateWorld(self):
        for number in range(0, self.height):
            self.WorldDict[number] = [self.defaultchar for _ in self.width]

You can read up on the issue more here

The values in your dictionary all refer to the same (list) object.
A neater way to do this would be to construct WorldDict lazily by using a property decorator and a dictionary comprehension.
Something like this:
import json # only used for output formatting

class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, defaultchar):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.defaultchar = defaultchar

    @property
    def WorldDict(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_WorldDict"):
            self._WorldDict = {n: [self.defaultchar] * self.width for n in range(self.height)}
        return self._WorldDict


world = World(5, 5, "-")
world.WorldDict[0][1] = "P"
print(json.dumps(world.WorldDict, indent=2))

Output (partial):
{
  "0": [
    "-",
    "P",
    "-",
    "-",
    "-"
  ],
  "1": [
    "-",
    "-",
    "-",
    "-",
    "-"
  ],

